# How to remove smaller sentences from a document with multiple paragraphs

Tags: regex

In a paragraph with sequence of sentences, I want to remove sentences which are made up of less than 3 words. Sentences are ended by full stops.

**Sample Input:**
Topic: India. This is a sample sentence. . The gdp of India is x.x in 2017  . There may be multiple spaces between and after the period. India. Foreign Policy. 2.5. 4.5 . Some random decimal numbers too. email: abc@google.com .

**Sample Output:**
This is a sample sentence. The gdp of India is x.x in
2017. There may be multiple spaces between and after the period. Some random decimal numbers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

Due to the nature of the text you are trying to match and what you're doing with it, this regex may not work for all your cases but it does work on the text sample you provided.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/u9itzC/1)

```
(?:^|(?<=\.\s))(?:\S*\s*){1,3}(?:\.\s+|\.$)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> Topic: India. This is a sample sentence. . The gdp of India is x.x in
>   2017 . There may be multiple spaces between and after the period.
>   India. Foreign Policy. 2.5. 4.5 . Some random decimal numbers too.
>   email: abc@google.com .

#### Output

> This is a sample sentence. The gdp of India is x.x in 2017 . There may
>   be multiple spaces between and after the period. Some random decimal
>   numbers too.

---

### Explanation

- `(?:^|(?<=\.\s))` Match either of the following

  - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
  - `(?<=\.\s)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a literal dot followed by a whitespace character
- `(?:\S*\s*){1,3}` Match the following between 1 and 3 times

  - `\S*` Match any number of non-whitespace characters
  - `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `(?:\.\s+|\.$)` Match either of the following

  - `\.\s+` Match a literal dot followed by one or more whitespace characters
  - `\.$` Match a literal dot and assert position at the end of the line